# Messaging Application Database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-structures

The app should allow Private (Direct 1 to 1 messaging) and Public (Groups) Chatrooms.

Here's what I'm thinking

```
Table User
---------
UserID
Name
.
Table ChatRoom
--------------
ChattRoomID
Type //Either public or Private
.
Table Members
----------
MemberID //This is a foreign key from 'User'
ChatRoom //This is a foriegn key to 'ChatRoomId'
.
Table Messages
---------
ID
Sender //foreign key to MemberID or UserID
ChatRoom //foreign key from 'Chatroom'
content
```

The way that this works is even for a private conversation it creates a chatroom but there would only be 2 `Member`s in that `Chatroom`. In case of a group chat, `Chatroom` would have multiple `Members`

Is this a poor design? Any ideas in general would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a chatroom for private messages isn't a good idea, because - as you write - in that case you will have many occasional chatrooms with only two members. Storing this chatrooms incl. the members will not have any benefits. You have to separate this two types (private conversations and chatroom messaging).

So, instead of that you can create new tables just for such private conversations like this:

```
Table Conversations
-----------------
Id
User1
User2
Started
```

and

```
Table ConvMessages
-----------------
Id
ConversationId
Sender
Content
Date
```

And the other tables (`ChatRoom`, `Members`, `Messages`) will only serve for really chatroom conversations.